# UWP Implementing a ShyHeader

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app

I basically copied code from [here](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=869003) and then changed controls to mine.

There are two problems with my implementation.

1. The header disappears after it is scrolled.
2. The CommandBar is misplaced after the page that has the control is reloaded.

The second one can be fixed by commented out the code below, but I am not sure if I can still achieve what I want, since I cannot see the header after scrolling.

```
        ExpressionNode buttonOffsetAnimation = progressNode * -100;
        buttonVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", buttonOffsetAnimation);
```

ShyHeader is implemented in the [HeaderPlaylistControl](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/Controls/HeaderedPlaylistControl.xaml.cs) and code is at the bottom.

`HeaderPlaylistControl` is used in [AlbumPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/AlbumPage.xaml), [MyFavoritesPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/MyFavoritesPage.xaml) and [PlaylistsPage](https://github.com/SeakyLuo/SMPlayer/blob/master/SMPlayer/PlaylistsPage.xaml).

Comment: I check the code, everything looks correct, but only this line does not looks  run  `headerVisual.StartAnimation("Offset.Y", headerTranslationAnimation);`

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Oh, I thought the problem might be the opacity goes to 0 or the second last block of code is not working. Since you think that line does not run (commenting that out indeed doesn't affect the animation), how should I fix it?

Comment: currently, I have no good idea, I need consult with production team further.